# Aligning divs in a header

Tags: html, css

```css
.header {
 background-color: yellow;
 font-family: 'Arial';
 display: inline-block;
}

.leftheader{
 float: left;
}

#Logo{
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: 700;
 display: inline-block;
}

#LogoLTD{
 font-size: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.rightheader{
 display: flex;
 float: right;
}

.rightheader a{
 color: black;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">

 <div class="leftheader">
   <div id="Logo">COMPANY NAME</div>
   <div id="LogoLTD">LIMITED</div>
  </div>

 <div class="rightheader">
     <a href="/home.html">HOME</a>
     <a href="/who.html">WHO</a>
     <a href="/contact.html">CONTACT</a>
 </div>

</section>
```

I have been trying to make a header for my site but I can't get the aligning right.

I want to have my links on the right of the page inside the yellow box.

The yellow colour should be inside the header class.

Then the leftheader div and the rightheader div should be inside the header class. And they should be positioned on the left and right but I cannot get this to work whatever I do :(

My HTML is:

```
<section class="header">

 <div class="leftheader">
   <div id="Logo">COMPANY NAME</div>
   <div id="LogoLTD">LIMITED</div>
  </div>

 <div class="rightheader">
     <a href="/home.html">HOME</a>
     <a href="/who.html">WHO</a>
     <a href="/contact.html">CONTACT</a>
 </div>

</section>
```

My CSS is:

```
.header {
 background-color: yellow;
 font-family: 'Arial';
 display: inline-block;
}

.leftheader{
 float: left;
}

#Logo{
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: 700;
 display: inline-block;
}

#LogoLTD{
 font-size: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.rightheader{
 display: flex;
 float: right;
}

.rightheader a{
 color: black;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a snippet or js-fiddle with your code please?

Comment: there you go, someone did it for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using flex. Check out the code below.

```css
.header {
 background-color: yellow;
 font-family: 'Arial';
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}

.leftheader{
 display: flex;
 align-items: flex-end;
}

#Logo{
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: 700;
 display: inline-block;
}

#LogoLTD{
 font-size: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.rightheader{
 display: flex;
}

.rightheader a{
 color: black;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">

 <div class="leftheader">
   <div id="Logo">COMPANY NAME</div>
   <div id="LogoLTD">LIMITED</div>
  </div>

 <div class="rightheader">
     <a href="/home.html">HOME</a>
     <a href="/who.html">WHO</a>
     <a href="/contact.html">CONTACT</a>
 </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Thats amazing thanks! However, is there any way i can keep the "LIMITED" text on the same line as "COMPANY NAME" so that it is not aligned in middle of the yellow box? thanks

Comment: I made some edits to my first comment. Can you check and let me know if thats what you are looking for?

Comment: That is perfect!!!! Thank you soooo much!!! been playing with this all of last night haha.

Comment: Haha you are welcome. I would appreciate if you marked my answer as correct :)

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @SebGreen It doesn't matter. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Sorry about that. Instead of using display: inline block, I used display: flex. And then to align company name and limited word I used align-items: flex-end.

Answer (score 0):

Just add width: 100% to your header, things will look more like you want them:

```
.header {
    background-color: yellow;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! When i add that it makes the box how I want it but the links are put in the top right hand corner rather than aligning centrally? thank you

Comment: when you say align centrally do you mean vertical align? meaning they are supposed to have the same space at the top and bottom? (but still located at the right side of the bar) or horizontally aligned? meaning the links are actually supposed to go in the middle of the yellow line?

Comment: sorry, vertically aligned :) someone else has answered it though but thank you very much for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work.

```
.header {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 background: yellow;
 padding: 8px;
}

.leftheader {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  width: 60%;
}

.rightheader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Hello @Rob I am new here so my apologies.
I simply played with the width of leftheader and rightheader in relative values.
Since they are inside the header div, leftheader will cover 60% of its parent element and the rightheader will cover 40%.

Comment: Please don't treat Stack Overflow like most forums. It's not. Read the Help Center and be a great contributor.

Comment: Hi @TabrezKhan, welcome to StackOverflow; nice to have you. Keep answering. Keep questioning. Would be cool if you read the official how to's.